# Chaincode instantiate error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxxx

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

My chaincode have a go dependency which needs C library.

I used vendor command to package dependencies and I can my vendor folder contains all the required .so files.

Chaincode installation goes fine without any problem.

But at chaincode instantiation, I am getting error:

```
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 2 "# github.com/chaincode/awesomeProject/vendor/github.com/wasmerio/go-ext-wasm/wasmer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwasmer_runtime_c_api
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This means it's unable to find the required dependencies at chaincode instantiation.

Any pointers on how it can be resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the CLI to package/install the chain code (`peer chaincode install ...`), then this won't work since as the command filters out all file extensions other than

```
var includeFileTypes = map[string]bool{
".c":    true,
".h":    true,
".s":    true,
".go":   true,
".yaml": true,
".json": true,
```

}

You can probably get this to work if you use the Node.js or Java SDK to package and install the chaincode.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Gari. It would be difficult for me to switch to JAVA/Node as the required dependencies are available in golang only. Is there any way to temporary install it with all the system dependencies i.e. .so files? Like adding .so extensions in the above array by modifying in cli or installing it directly in peer before instantiating?

Comment: Sorry ... I meant using the Node SDK to package chaincode ... but the chaincode would still be written in Golang.  But I now realize that likely will not work either as the shared lib won't be available in the baseos container used to run chaincode.

I'll try to look at this later as the only way to do this is going to be to use both a custom ccenv image and a custom image for the go chaincode runtime

Comment: Also ... so it looks like you are trying to add wasm into chaincode?  Interesting

Comment: Just out of interest it may be possible to run wasm code when using node.js chaincode as I believe node 8 has wasm support enabled.